# Track Web app visitors with Google Analytics

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, analytics

I'm trying to track visitors who are going to my website via my iPhone/iPad web app (in fullscreen mode).

I added this code (above the native Google Analytics tracker):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           if (window.navigator.standalone == true) {
        _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
            5,
            'Full Screen Mode visitors',
            'full-screen-mode-visitors',
            3
            ]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            }
</script>
```

But no custom variable appears in Google Analytics... Is there something wrong in my code? My web app is loading fine in a full screen mode, but no custom variable are being recorded in Google Analytics.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK to me.
But maybe you could try to add an if else statement to track those are NOT in web app mode? With a different value of course.
If they show up the, missing custom variable in Google Analytics must have something to do with the window.navigator.standalone property, and not the setCustomVar itself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice -> I'm going to add one "else" statement to track those who are not in web app mode and will let you know about the results. It's very difficult to work on this feature because results are not immediate, I have to visit my web app and wait some hours to check if custom variable has been added in Google Analytics...

Comment: Very strange. I added the else statement yesterday associated with a new custom variable called "Normal visitors", and Google Analytics recorded only one visit with this custom variable since yesterday (whereas there were thousand visits) ?

Comment: I replaced the previous code with this one to track web app users as events: `if (("standalone" in window.navigator) & window.navigator.standalone){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Bookmarked', 'HomeScreen']);
   }` but without any success... anyone to help me to reach my goal?

Comment: This one workes for me: http://cpm-calc.com/script.js (see the last 21 lines)  Could also recommend Google Analytics Debugger extension in Google Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna